# extracting a number from a text file in C++

Tags: c++

I have a text file with the following layout:

```
step=fixed step start=100 step=1

32

112

step=fixed step start =211 step=1

11

34
```

and so on
I need to extract the numbers 100 and 211 respectively i.e. the start values as integers in my code and carry out some operations.

Comment: Maybe look into [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)?

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "file read" or "file parse".  It's already been answered many times.

Answer (score 0):

getchar and use space as delimiter. Or use scanf and formatted string. (but it still needs some spaces between words and numbers.)

```
Example:
scanf("%s %s %s %s %d",variables..);
scanf("%d",var);
scanf("%d",var1);
```

since you know format its quite easy. If it is from file use fscanf.

Comment: Buffer overrun issues.  Use `std::string` and `std::getline` instead. Also use `std::istringstream` for extracting from the `std::string`.

Comment: Maybe a man is using something low level. If he has iostream.h he can use those. Those are even easer that you mentioned.

Comment: For the OP, there is no need to use low level I/O.  The OP should consider correctness and safety first.  The C++ streams may be slower, but they are safer.  If the file is huge or is the bottleneck, using block reading and parsing in memory would be the preferred method.